# Please How to Parse a Web Site with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, web, simple-html-dom

I do a simple project in my department. I want to call the movie at the movie site, but I don't know how to write a regular expression. I've tried everything in a variety of ways, but I can't. I don't know how to fill out the code. Let me know. I am not using jquery, but I am only using simple html dom, snooping.

[image]

Comment: what do you want from us, and given the image of code?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. This is not a work for me community.....

Comment: Please post your code here. Additionally, what is the PHP's relation to jQuery, you are mentioning?

Comment: Let me start off by saying HTML should not be parsed with regular expressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to have a list of all times, put them in a n array with something like this(you do not need regex for this if you are usin php dom parser):

```
$timesArray = [];
foreach($html->find('div[class=info-timetable] li a em') as $times) {
        $timesArray[] = $times->plaintext;
};
```

PS: Never post images with your code, instead paste the code in your question mate!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It was the first question I asked.
I wrote a code to the question, but I didn't know what to do, so I attached it as a picture.
Thank you very much indeed!









복사하기

Comment: :) Hope it helps, if it works out for you remember to accept the answer. Cheers!